# Display Text only for selected attribute values

Tags: attributes, magento2.4.5, graphql

In Headless magento project, there is condition written by previous developers in javascript

if there is a value assigned for attribute : `is_outlet_available` , than some text should display, otherwise text should not display in product view page

```
products(
            filter: { is_outlet_available: { in: [$key] }, sku: { in: [$sku] } }
        )
```

I want to change as if the value of the attribute is 3 or 5 or 6 for that product, than only text should display in product view page, so i changed code as below :

```
filter: { is_outlet_available: { in: [3||5||6] }, sku: { in: [$sku] } }
```

but still the text is displaying.

[image]

here is a full code : https://pastebin.com/CrS2ERW5

Comment: can you share your schema.graphqls ?

Comment: please check : https://pastebin.com/5f2EuXq1 , here is folder structure : https://prnt.sc/VpuQi0glcPLh

Comment: Yes, I have provided a solution. Please check it, and if it is not working, update me. If you encounter any issues, kindly provide more information so that I can assist you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I created an attribute following your provided example and incorporated customizations into the product query. Please add the code below to your module and check the product query.**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
interface ProductInterface {
    is_outlet_available: [String] @doc(description: "Product Custom Attribute Show")
      @resolver(
        class: "VendorName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\AddCustomAttribute"
      )
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver/Product**

**AddCustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\Product;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;

class AddCustomAttribute implements ResolverInterface
{
    protected $productFactory;

    protected $attributeOptionsManagement;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionsManagement
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->attributeOptionsManagement = $attributeOptionsManagement;
    }

    public function resolve(
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field $field,
        $context,
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $product = $value['model'];
        $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($product->getId());
        $optionData = explode(',', $_product->getData('is_outlet_available') ?? '');
        $attributeOptions = $this->attributeOptionsManagement->getItems(ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, 'is_outlet_available');
        $featuredOptions = [];
        if (count($optionData)) {
            foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
                if (in_array($attributeOption->getValue(), $optionData)) {
                    $featuredOptions[$attributeOption->getValue()] = $attributeOption->getLabel();
                }
            }
        }
        return $featuredOptions;
    }
}
```

**Product Query with your attribute value:**

```
{
  products(filter: { sku: { eq: "YOUR_SKU" } }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      url_key
      is_outlet_available
    }
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now, the value is available within the product data, allowing you to directly check it in your Headless React code.**